# How to set CSS animation speed without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

This question is about speed of CSS animation.

```css
.div1{
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #A1BDAF;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content{
    color: white;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;

    animation: moving 4s ease-in-out forwards;
    transition: width linear;
}

@keyframes moving{

    from{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    to{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        margin-left: 100%;
    }

}
```

```html
    <div class = "div1">
        <h1 class = "content">
            The only thing that matters now is everything You think of me
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class = "div1">
        <h1 class = "content">
            I want to fix the speed of running text animation 
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class = "div1">
        <h1 class = "content">
            regardless of the length of the text.
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class = "div1">
        <h1 class = "content">
            Is there any way to set not duration but speed of animation
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class = "div1">
        <h1 class = "content">
            with out JavaScript?
        </h1>
    </div>
```

As above, the duration of the animation is fixed, so the *shorter* the text is, the *slower* the progress, and vice versa. But I want to make the animation speed the same.

In JavaScript, It could be expressible as

```
sampleDom.style.animationDuration = (sampleDom.scrollWidth) / (speed) +"s";
```

but I want to write it in CSS without JavaScript.

How to set CSS animation speed the same regardless length of text without JavaScript?

Comment: CSS does not know how much text you have in those elements. You can not do this using CSS alone.

Comment: @CBroe Oh, very sad news...  
  
  
After the code transplanted, I was worried that it would get a little heavier, so I tried to write CSS as much as possible, but it seems difficult..
 
Thank you for leaving a kind comment

Comment: @CBroe with some craziness it's possible ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea where you can consider the use of `position:sticky` but I will change how the animation should work.

Using CSS (or even JS) it's impossible to have at once:

1. the same start
2. the same end
3. the same speed.

You can only have 2 of them. In your solution you had the (1) and (2) and below you will have the (2) and (3)

```css
.container {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.div1 {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 300px 0, 300px 100%, 0 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  margin:5px 0;
  padding:0.5em 0;
  background: #A1BDAF;
  position: relative;
  animation: moving 6s ease-in-out forwards;
  left: 0;
}

.content span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

@keyframes moving {
  to {
    left: calc(300px - 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    <h1 class="content">
      <span>The only thing that matters now is everything You think of me</span>
    </h1>

    <h1 class="content">
      <span>I want to fix the speed of running text animation </span>
    </h1>

    <h1 class="content">
      <span> regardless of the length of the text.</span>
    </h1>

    <h1 class="content">
      <span> Is there any way to set not duration but speed of animation</span>
    </h1>

    <h1 class="content">
      <span> with out JavaScript?</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here you have (1) and (3). I know it's a crazy solution but be patient ...

```css
.container {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.div1 {
  clip-path: polygon(calc(100% - 300px) 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, calc(100% - 300px) 100%);
  display: inline-flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform:translateX(calc(300px - 100%));
  overflow:hidden;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  margin:5px 0;
  padding:0.5em 0;
  background: #A1BDAF;
  position: relative;
  animation: moving 6s ease-in-out forwards;
  left: 0;
}

.content span {
  position: sticky;
  right:0;
  float:right;
  min-width:300px;
}

@keyframes moving {
  from {
    left: calc(100% - 300px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    <h1 class="content">
      <span>The only thing that matters now is everything You think of me</span>
    </h1>

    <h1 class="content">
      <span>I want to fix the speed of running text animation </span>
    </h1>

    <h1 class="content">
      <span> regardless of the length of the text.</span>
    </h1>

    <h1 class="content">
      <span> Is there any way to set not duration but speed of animation</span>
    </h1>

    <h1 class="content">
      <span> with out JavaScript?</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main trick in both solutions is to make all the elements the same width (defined by the longest one). To do this, I considered a flexbox container with a column direction. This will make sure the speed is the same since the width is the same then using sticky I block the inner element from moving when it reach one of the edges.

Comment: Wow.. this is a very very awesome and fascinating method!!!!
  
by adding space in front of the text, and set its direction to the column, alignment of contents are all fit and get the same width so marquee speed can be the same!!!

Comment: I am very surprised twice for this could be able without JavaScript, and this fantastic method!!

Thank you very much!! 
I owe to you since yesterday!  
Thanks for the very kind and impressive answers and I wish you have a peaceful day!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @J4BEZ yes CSS is impressive, you have no idea what you can do with it if you find the needed trick ;)

Comment: Very Impressive and Very fascinating ever !! I'll keep going and explore it more deeply! Thank you!!

Answer (score -2):

```
transition: (action) sec;
```

OR

```
transition: all 1s;
```

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, but the transition doesn't seem to solve it.
      
If the text length changes, the length of the animation for each element should be different (D = V * T), but the transition seems to be too much to control the speed of the animation.
       
Thank you for your reply and I hope you have a good day.