# Marquee in pure CSS, different string length but same speed

Tags: css

I need to display different `marquees` done with `css` as such:

```
animation: scroll-left 40s linear infinite;
 
@keyframes scroll-left {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

Simple. The thing is that I have 3 different string lengths but need these 3 string lengths to go at the same speed so **that they can be aligned when they are moving**. With a bit of JavaScript, I therefore decided to create a function that
1 - finds the longest string length value and 2 - make all these strings equal in length (by adding white spaces after) before generating the marquees.

Even though these marquees have the same speed and their strings the same length (I doubled check), they are not aligned. How come is it possible? **How can I make them aligned?**

I'm attaching here what I would like to get (with the same text content - img #1 ) and what I currently have - img #2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If your text isn’t monospaced (and your font doesn’t look to be monospaced) then string length won’t result in equally sized elements. I’d suggest wrapping the text in a `<span>` within the marquee element, then finding the widest `<span>` element and making all the `<span>` elements the width of the longest.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61727529/8620333

Comment: @Temani: nicely done; for some reason I discounted the use of flex items, and instead came up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/18qv2b79/; though it's worth saying that I think your answer to the question you link is far better.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica yes we can drop the use of flexbox (not sure why I used it, probably faced some strange result upon testing ..). This said, you can add your code below, it worth an answer ;)

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonicai, don't hesitate to put your code below and I'll gladly mark it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here an example where varying lengths texts are move at an identical pace

```css
p {
  animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="line-height: 60px;font-size: 16px;white-space:nowrap">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
</div>
<div style="line-height: 60px;font-size: 16px;white-space:nowrap">
  <p>Ut sed placeat aperiam quod nostrum itaque blanditiis soluta!</p>
</div>
<div style="line-height: 60px;font-size: 16px;white-space:nowrap">
  <p>Aliquid fuga molestias aut magni, pariatur doloremque, voluptas ipsa nobis ipsum voluptatibus ab.</p>
</div>
<div style="line-height: 60px;font-size: 16px;white-space:nowrap">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut sed placeat aperiam quod nostrum itaque blanditiis soluta! Aliquid fuga molestias aut magni, pariatur doloremque, voluptas ipsa nobis ipsum voluptatibus ab.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Most browsers seem to still support the html tag, you can learn how to modify the features [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)
also also, that website contains what websites still support it or not, the html tag is doing what you are trying to accomplish, but simpler and without the hassle

```css
p{
width:500px;
animation: scroll-left 40s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes scroll-left {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<p>henlo</p>
```

```html
<marquee>henlo</marquee>
<marquee>henlo</marquee>
<marquee>henlo</marquee>
```

Comment: This does not reply the question, which is: how to keep the same speed when you have different text lengths. But thanks anyway!