# adjust transition duration according to move distance

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

In my example when a user hovers over a text that is too long for its container

it will start scrolling so the entire content can be read.

My problem is that I don't know how to adjust the transition duration

according to the length of the content.

I want that the text scrolls with a consistent speed across all containers.

```css
body > div
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 15px 0px 0px #404040 inset, -15px 0px 0px #404040 inset;
}
div div
{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  height: 50px;
  background: #404040;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  float: left;
  transform: translate(0px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

div:hover div
{
  width: unset;
  overflow: unset;
  text-overflow: unset;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
  transform: translate(calc(200px - 100%));
}
```

```html
<div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</div>
</div>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61729592/8620333

Comment: None of the provided answers there are really satisfying.