# How To Set Fixed Animation Speed By Using CSS Only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a fixed animation speed for my notification widget but in this code, I'm having a problem and the problem is when I'm using "animation: 30s linear infinite;" The speed is automatically getting slower & faster, which I don't want. This means, when I have more paragraph tags the speed increases and when I have less paragraph tags the speed slows down but I want a specific/ fixed speed no matter how many paragraph tags I have, like Marquee tag.

```css
.short-message {
   border:10px solid #303030;
   width: auto;
   height: 370px;
}
.scroll-up {
   height: 370px;
   overflow:hidden;
   display: inline-block;
}
.upper {
   animation: scroll 30s linear infinite;
   display: block;
   padding-top:370px;
}
.upper:hover {
animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  to {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

.karo {
   color: black;
}
.headings {
   background: #303030;
   color: white;
   
   padding: 5px;
   text-align: center;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
.n-p {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: red;
   padding: 10px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: red;
}
.blink {
  color: grey;
  animation: blinker .7s  infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="short-message">
    <div class="scroll-up">
       <div class="upper">

        <h3 class="headings">NOTIFICATIONS</h3>

<p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 1:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>

<p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 2:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>

<p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your valuable time & suggestions.

Comment: maybe is something with `%` value, try to use a not relative measure (like px, vh, rem, or etc...)  so it be equal also with more element or less

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61729592/8620333

Answer (score 0):

you need an absolute measure like *px*, *rem*... 
or if you want a relative: make sure the measure doesn't depend on the height of the parent element

- like *vh* depends on display height. but not the `.upper` is a good option
- or *px* if there is less element the *px* value remain the same, if more element the *px* is still the same

in fact, using *100%* automatically changes the value for you, if there is less element or more... (in most the cases this is amazing but in you case, you don't like this behavior)

**after the change:**

```css
/* your code */

@keyframes scroll {
    to {
        transform: translateY(-100vh); /* before was: -100% */
    }
}

/* your code */
```

in the beta below, I will show you the animation with the time that remains on the screen, so you visualize what happens

(do not copy the code, the snippet below is only for beta... try to change with your own value... you don't need js)

```js
let AnimationDuration = 30; // seconds

function TimeRemained() {
  if (AnimationDuration > 0) {
    AnimationDuration--;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = AnimationDuration;
    setTimeout(TimeRemained, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(TimeRemained);
    console.log("30 second is finished");
  }
}

TimeRemained();
```

```css
.short-message {
  border: 10px solid #303030;
  width: auto;
  height: 370px;
}

.scroll-up {
  height: 370px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.upper {
  animation: scroll 30s linear infinite;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 370px;
}

.upper:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  to {
    transform: translateY(-100vh);
  }
}

.karo {
  color: black;
}

.headings {
  background: #303030;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.n-p {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

.blink {
  color: grey;
  animation: blinker .7s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="time">
    30 seconds
  </div>
  <div class="short-message">
    <div class="scroll-up">
      <div class="upper">

        <h3 class="headings">NOTIFICATIONS</h3>

        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 1:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>

        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 2:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>

        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
        <p class="n-p"><span class="blink">➤</span><a target="blank" href=""><span class="karo">&nbsp;LINE 3:</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```