Automatically animate text ONLY if text is too long for div area
I have an application that pulls in variable destination names. The text area has a set width, however sometimes the text that comes in will be too long for the text area, so in that case id like the text to automatically animate to slide the text over, perhaps some kind of pingpong animation to fit the text in and move side to side.
i have created a jquery animation that if the text is too long it will auto scroll, a bit like an old school marquee tag, however , i dont want the destination name to have to scroll all the way and then restart once all text has scrolled out of view. I'm looking for examples from the community of a better way of doing this.


.destination {
    height: 40px;
  width: 250px;
    left: 0; 
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  }
  
  .row1 {
  top:0;
  }
  
  .row2 {
  top:100px;
  }
<div class="destination row1">
                    Short name
                   </div>
                   <div class="destination row2">
                    Long destination name
                   </div>




Not exactly, as i only want it to move if the text is too long for the text area. So in my example, short name stays still but long name moves.

Is it this? 1. The animation should only work if the characters are longer than the box, 2. When it reaches the front and end of the characters, it should move in reverse.

Yes that's exactly what i want, with perhaps a slight pause as it reaches either end so it can be readable

You can use the fact that the translateX 100% value is the width of the text in this snippet.
Hence 250px - 100% in a translateX is negative for the long text and positive for the short text.
The animation in this snippet uses this to get the maximum of 0px and this difference. In this way the short text doesn't move and the long one does.
The slight pauses at either end are created by the timing intervals in the keyframes.
Note: the snippet puts the two text elements into a container which defines a variable --w - it's width (250px in the question). This is used in the calculation and is made a var simply so it's easier to alter it if required.


<style>
  .container {
    --w: 250px;
    width: var(--w);
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .destination {
    font-size: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    animation: move 6s linear infinite forwards;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  @keyframes move {
    0%,
    10%,
    90%,
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    40%,
    60% {
      transform: translateX(calc(-1 * max(0px, 100% - var(--w))));
    }
  }
  
  .row1 {
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .row2 {
    top: 100px;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="destination row1">
    Short name
  </div>
  <div class="destination row2">
    Long destination name
  </div>
</div>




Brilliant thanks this works well. The only issue i have with using keyframes is they need to specify a time value, which means the longer the text, the quicker the animation. Is there a way of the speed of movement being the same no matter the character length?

You may need JS for this, I’ll ponder!

It’s just possible that the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727529/how-to-set-css-animation-speed-without-javascript can help but I’m afraid I haven’t got time to look further at the moment. Good luck.
